# ASP.NET Core: what is the best way to pass information from header to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core controller with few methods requiring specific data to be passed in header. To be clear the data is JWT-token containing some session info. To retrieve the information stored in the token I need to perform few actions:

1. check header exists (if not return bad request)
2. decode jwt-token to json string
3. map json string to a model instance

At the moment I perform all that steps in controller methods but that's bad practice since that is code duplication. I was thinking about some elegant solution like creating an custom attribute and decorating methods with it. But I couldn't find a way to pass data from attribute to controller action. It seems to me that attributes are designed for another type of tasks.

What is optimal solution for that is ASP.NET Core?

Comment: i recommend using one of the many existing authentication-providers that parse the JWT.

Comment: If you want to stay in asp core authentication concepts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you'll need to adjust your flow. If we're talking about "someting other" you could create a helper method / service / shared base controller class or extension method. For all other options some more context would help.

Comment: The optimal solution is to let the Authentication middleware handle authentication . ASP.NET Core [already handles JWT authentication and authorization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) through the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package

Comment: I use the token as temporary information storage in step-by-step registration wizard, so I don't think that authorization engine should be used there.

Comment: @VladimirZotov that's not what JWT tokens are for. Besides, you *do* need that middleware to contact the issuer and decrypt the token. Any claims in the token will be accessible as Claims. The linked article shows how to use a custom `office` element, which is retrieved with `context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Issuer == "http://localhost:5000/" && c.Type == "office").Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a TypeFilterAttribute and decorate your controller/actions with this.
Inside the TypeFilterAttribute you can do your logic with the headers and add the result inside the HttpContext, which can then be retrieve in the controller.

```
public class TokenAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public TokenAttribute() : base(typeof(TokenFilterImpl))
    {
    }

    public class TokenFilterImpl : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        
        public ItemExistsFilterImpl()
        {
        }

        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
            ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            
            // Validate your headers here
            //context.HttpContext.Request.Headers...

            
            if (isNotValid)
            {
                context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult($"Some reason");
                return;
            }

            // Add the required object to be retrieved from the controller
            context.HttpContext.Items.Add("xxyyzz", modelInstance);

            await next();
        }
    }
}

[HttpGet()]
// Decorate with your filterAttribute
[Token]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    // retrive the modelInstance
    var config = HttpContext.Items["xxyyzz"] as InstanceObjectClass;

    return Ok();
}
```